# What are the implications of relativity of Mathematics?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

I came across the idea that the same statement can be true in one model while not true in another, while both models are being consistent. An example is "Is the sum of the angles of a triangle equal to 180 degrees?" While true in Euclidean geometry, it is not in non-Euclidean. Thus, this introduces relativity to mathematics.

So, my question is what are some philosophical implications of this? Where can one go from here? For example, will a model that assumes both Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometry be inconsistent even both are consistent individually? Can both coexist consistently?

Comment: I suspect this might mean that we will need more than mathematics, or rationality, to tell us what is real. Welcome to this SE!

Comment: See [Mathematical structuralism](https://www.iep.utm.edu/m-struct/) : "Some philosophers postulate an ontology of structures, and claim that the subject matter of a given branch of mathematics is a particular structure, or a class of structures."

Comment: This page does not discuss non-Euclidean geometry, as far as I know, however I think you may find this website interesting. Prof. John Norton https://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/significance_GR_geometry/Einstein_on_Kant.html

Comment: Why does your example introduce "relativity" instead of showing that starting with a general statement like "all triangles" may be too general?

Comment: There might be a triangle that satisfies a certain property where its angles sum up to 180 in both Euclidean and non-Euclidean. Sadly, I am not an expert. My introduction of "relativity" was based on this text https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/27964201.pdf . They use speficially the hyperbolic geometry as the non-Euclidean one being compared. I am not sure of dependability of the text linked though.

Comment: A model that incorporates both Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometries is called [Kleinian geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_geometry). It is not inconsistent, they just appear as special cases. Mathematical pluralism simply means that there is a multiverse of mathematical systems, none truer than others (some do include inconsistent systems, but this is not popular). For some discussion see [Balaguer's Mathematical Pluralism and Platonism](https://www.calstatela.edu/sites/default/files/users/u1241/mathematical_pluralism_and_platonism.pdf)

Comment: It shows that we can use math to model a variety of systems; but that we can't turn to math to discover truth. Counterexample to what I just said: 5 is prime, and that's clearly a truth. Discuss.

Comment: Thanks everyone. @Conifold I think this answers my question but I cannot upvote as I am new.

Answer (score 2):

All mathematics is basically taking certain axioms and deriving interesting theorems from them.  It should be no surprise that taking different axioms can result in different theorems.  There is no relativity here, just differing axioms.

Euclidean geometry includes the parallel postulate, which is that, given a line and a point not on that line, precisely one line parallel to the original line goes through the original point.  Typically, the geometries we call non-Euclidean have other variations of it.  Riemann created a geometry with no parallel lines, and Lobachevsky created one with multiple parallel lines going through a point.

These are frequently modeled by constructing a 2D geometry on a flat plane, a rounded surface, or a saddle-shaped surface, respectively.  A geometry can easily include all possibilities, by allowing for possible curvature of a plane or space or whatever.

The major philosophical effect was when non-Euclidean geometries became known, and it was realized that geometry didn't really determine anything about the world, but was just a description.  Philosophers that predate these developments sometimes took geometry as an example of finding things out about the world just by reasoning, and philosophers since realize that doesn't work.

Comment: "All mathematics is basically taking certain axioms and deriving interesting theorems from them." Only if your knowledge of math was learned in philosophy class, and not a very good one. In the real world the theorems are discovered first and then the axioms are developed to support them. For evidence see the entire history of mathematics. Gauss never heard of set theory, was he not doing math in your view?

Comment: @user4894 Intuition is surely important for a professional mathematician, but in the end mathematics is proving theorems. And the only way to prove a theorem in a mathematically acceptable way is deriving it from axioms, and from previously proved theorems based on such axioms. This has always been the case, even if the study of foundations of mathematics and metamathematics is fairly recent (in the past, some statements that are now theorems were taken as axioms).

Comment: @user4894 In addition, there have been serious drawbacks in relying too much on intuition, see for example the (partly in)famous [italian school of algebraic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_school_of_algebraic_geometry#Collapse_of_the_school)

Comment: @user4894 "Only if your knowledge of math was learned in philosophy class, and not a very good one. ...  Gauss never heard of set theory." That may be a bit harsh. In Gauss's day, for example, the associativity of addition was just "common sense" -- implicitly an "axiom" of basic arithmetic among several others. I'm sure he would have agreed with each of Peano's Axioms, and that one could indeed prove associativity from these axioms. With the axiomatization of set theory, one could, in turn, derive each of Peano's original axioms.

Comment: I got my answer with existence of Kleinian geometry. (but I cannot upvote! as I am a new member) But, reformulating my question would be "Can we have two consistent models that disagree on a statement and they cannot coexist in any supermodel?" So if this is possible, then what axioms we choose matter, otherwise we can end up with two incompatible models, and maybe someone can exemplify this situation with a real world case if this case is really possible.

Comment: @DanChristensen Do you believe that Gauss started with some axioms and said, "Let me see what theorems I can prove from these?" That's an extremely naive an incorrect view of how mathematicians work.

Comment: @user4894 How does one communicate even an formal mathematical proof to someone else? You must start, at the very least from an agreed-upon common number sense, including such things as the infinite succession of natural numbers (later codified by Peano and Dedekind), the commutativity and associativity of addition and multiplication and so on. These would be part of the implicit "axioms" that Gauss would have had to use in all of his proofs.

Comment: @DanChristensen "agreed upon common number sense" is a long way from mechanically cranking out theorems from a set of formal axioms. You are stretching to make a weak point that, absent your dialog with me, you probably don't even believe yourself.

Comment: @user4894 There nothing mechanical about writing proofs from formal axioms. You would know this if you had ever tried it for any substantial proof. And in any well-developed field, you would also have an extensive library of theorems that could be used in the same way that you would use axioms. In writing informal proofs you would also make use of such libraries of the axioms and theorems you had to learn from various courses, textbooks and journals.

Comment: @DanChristensen "There nothing mechanical about writing proofs from formal axioms." -- Are you responding to something I said? That's a very disingenuous remark.

Comment: @user4894 Was it you or an impostor who wrote something about "mechanically cranking out theorems from a set of formal axioms?"

Comment: @DanChristensen You quoted my literal words; but so radically misconstrued my meaning that if I were in an uncharitable mood I'd call your interpretation disingenuous. However in the spirit of SE's "be nice" campaign of recent weeks, I'll say rather that I do feel misunderstood. It's a minor point either way.